Does aftermarket 12v automotive headlights need regulated voltage?
I am converting an old 12VAC headlight system to 12VDC to use aftermarket LED headlights(H4 socket). Now commercially available LED headlights obviously have drivers in them to control the currents in the LEDs. My question is if it is okay to supply them with 12 sqrt(2) VDC instead of 12VDC or do I need to regulate the voltage also?

Ref: https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/motorcycle-12vac-to-dc-headlight-wiring-circuit.164160/
Thanks in advance.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does your system use a battery? In automotive applications, electricity is pulled from the battery and the alternator replenishes what is used. This means the system is regulated by the battery (as well as there being a regulator on the alternator). The thing is, if your system isn't using a battery, is this even an MVM&R question?

It's a motorcycle and it does have a battery. But the output from the alternator has two sides. One is converted to DC and is associated with the battery. However the other AC side was being used to directly run the halogen lamp. In order to prevent overload I don't intend to used the DC circuit(I have already have a dead battery for this very reason).

It's an Indian bike, maybe in western countries everything is DC. But I hear dirt bikes there have similar topology.

Get the spec sheet for the aftermarket LED headlights. That will tell you the minimum and maximum allowable DC voltage. If the headlights have no spec sheet available, find a different LED headlight that does have a spec sheet.

Most automotive equipment is pretty tolerant of fluctuations in voltage, and unless it's particularly poorly made, I would expect it to work just fine even on 12VAC, possibly not as bright and some flickering though. You can address that with a voltage rectifier, and get DC from the AC side.
